# HSQLDB delete row(s) from JDBC resultset

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I have run into a couple of problems while trying to convert an existing JDBC application to use HSQLDB version 2.2.9 (Currently the codebase runs successfully on MySQL, ORACLE and SQLServer, but an embedded database seemed like a good option too).

I will ask the questions one at a time and separately (although they all relate to the JDBC `ResultSet.deleteRow()` method, supported since HSQLDB 2.0)

Why does `rs.next()` return false after calling `rs.deleteRow()`?

Here is a complete self contained code sample (including simple table creation, sample inserts, and deleting the table at the end):

```
    int deletedRows=0;
    try{
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mytestdb",
                 "SA", "");
        String createSQL =
                 "create table test (num INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, str VARCHAR(25))";
        Statement createStmt = c.createStatement();
        createStmt.execute(createSQL);
        createStmt.close();
        String ins = "insert into test (num,str) values (?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pStmt = c.prepareStatement(ins);
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            pStmt.setInt(1, i);
            pStmt.setString(2, "String"+i);
            pStmt.execute();
        }
        // there should now be 100 rows in the table
        String select = "SELECT * FROM test";
        PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(select, 
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();    
        rs.beforeFirst();
        while(rs.next()){
            int num = rs.getInt("num");
            if((num%7)==0){
                System.out.println("Deleting row:"+num);
                rs.deleteRow();
                deletedRows++;
            }
        }
        Statement dropStmt = c.createStatement();
        dropStmt.execute("drop table test;");
        dropStmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Deleted "+deletedRows+
                    " rows before exception: "+sqle.getMessage());
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When running the same code on MySQL database, the output shows that every 7th row is deleted:

> Deleting row:0
>
> Deleting row:7
>
> ...
>
> Deleting row: 98

On HSQLDB, the output is:

> Deleting row:0

The `rs.next()` returns false after the first call to `rs.deleteRow()`.

I cannot find any information in the HSQLDB javadoc. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: By the way, I know I could do the same deletion using a simple SQL delete statement, but that is not an option in the actual existing code (the deletion is not quite as simple as the example, and requires DB implementation specific SQL).

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the HSQLDB implementation of `ResultSet.deleteRow()`.

Comment: That is what I am thinking too, but I cannot find such a bug report. I'll have a look again and ask their dev team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the cursor holdability in the code:

```
c.prepareStatement(select,
     ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
     ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
     ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
```

The problem seems to be that HSQLDB JDBC driver uses `ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT` as the default value.

Answer (score 1):

As I also commented before, this sounds like a bug in the HSQLDB JDBC implementation. The JDBC 4.1 spec (section 15.2.4.2) says:

> After the method `deleteRow` has been called, the cursor will be positioned before the next valid row. If the deleted row is the last row, the cursor will be positioned after the last row.

This implies that the call to `next()` should have returned `true` (if the `ResultSet` contained more rows).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have a misconfiguation. For example you may have an older version of the HSQLDB jar in your classpath.

I get this output with the current SVN code. The JDBC code has not changed since 2.2.9.

```
Deleting row:0
Deleting row:7
Deleting row:14
Deleting row:21
Deleting row:28
Deleting row:35
Deleting row:42
Deleting row:49
Deleting row:56
Deleting row:63
Deleting row:70
Deleting row:77
Deleting row:84
Deleting row:91
Deleting row:98
```

Comment: I ran it on the 2.2.9 jar as well as on the 2.2.9 source and got the problem. It looks like the default cursor holdability is `CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT` and not `HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT` as it should be. If `c.prepareStatement(select,               ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT)` is used, the code works as expected. Maybe there should be a not in the JavaDoc for HSQLDB at least...

Comment: I think we should continue this discussion on the HSQLDB forums. I'll add my own answer and be done with it here...